# Copy/Mirror traffic to different port - iptables 

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, nginx, iptables

I have nginx running on port 80 and apache running on port 8080

I want to transfer all the traffic to both nginx and apache asynchronously i.e the performance of one server wont be dependent on the others. The reason being nginx will serve my website and apache will be used to run analytics on the traffic.

I want to mirror/copy the traffic on both port.  I dont want FORWARDING ...

I tried the following but in vain ...

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p tcp ! -s 127.0.0.1/32 --dport 80 -j TEE --gateway 127.0.0.1
```

and

```
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -p tcp -s 127.0.0.1/32 --dport 8080 -j SNAT --to 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Where am I going wrong ?

I am using iptables v1.4.10 on ubuntu 11.04

Comment: try this article: http://www.myopenrouter.com/article/10917/Port-Mirroring-Span-Port-Monitor-Port-with-iptables-on-NETGEAR-WGR614L/

Answer (score 2):

Simply impossible. You can only capture and analyse mirrored traffic with packet sniffer of some sort but not regular apache (or any process) listening on socket.